# Java while statement with two values sentinel-control loop won't terminate

Tags: java, while-loop, logic, sentinel, validity.js

Here we're trying to check the validity of the data that has been entered and I cannot figure out what the problem may be.  I want to check whether the "number" is either "1" or "2", and if not repeat the prompt until the correct data is entered.  The problem is once the correct data is entered it should break out of the loop, but I have found it stays in the loop.  I have posted the code & can post more of it for understanding.

```
while (( number != 1) || (number != 2)) // Check validity
{
   System.out.println ( "Number must be a 1 or a 2"); 
   System.out.print( "Enter number: " );
   number = input.nextInt();              
}  // end of while check validity
```

I have tested the statement `while(number != 1)` and `while(number !=2)` respectively and it seems to work fine, so it would seem the problem is within the logic of the statement `while(( number !=1) || (number != 2))`, so I thought maybe I was using the wrong kind of "or" statement, so tried the other or operands, and this didn't work, and (I can't remember I've done so much switching around) I think it errored out or didn't work logically either or didn't make a difference.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Your logic is incorrect.  It is always true that `number` will not equal `1` OR it will not equal `2`.  That is why your `while` loop will not terminate.

You need the logical-and operator, `&&`:

```
while (( number != 1) && (number != 2))
```

So that when `number` is not `1` AND `number` is not `2` the loop will continue.